# I want HTTPS authentication of MLFlow Tracking UI

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, mlflow

Basically I am working on the MLFlow Tracking UI. I have setup the MLFlow Tracking Server on a Remote Host. I want a HTTP Authentication for the Tracking Server. Can someone tell me what modification I need to do on this code? I want a self Signed Certificate Authority

```
# Run the docker command
sudo docker run --rm \
  --name oci-mlflow \
  --network host \
  -e MLFLOW_HOST=0.0.0.0 \
  -e MLFLOW_GUNICORN_OPTS='--log-level debug' \
  -e MLFLOW_PORT=5000 \
  -e MLFLOW_DEFAULT_ARTIFACT_ROOT="$MLFLOW_DEFAULT_ARTIFACT_ROOT" \
  -e MLFLOW_ARTIFACTS_DESTINATION="$MLFLOW_ARTIFACTS_DESTINATION" \
  -e BACKEND_PROVIDER=mysql \
  -e MLFLOW_BACKEND_STORE_URI="$MLFLOW_BACKEND_STORE_URI" \
  -e MLFLOW_SERVE_ARTIFACTS=1 \
  -e OCIFS_IAM_TYPE=instance_principal \
  "$DOCKER_IMAGE"
```

I just want a modification to this code.